# remove whitespace from beginning of second column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have a whitespace separated file that looks like:

```
12  12.57428314.57490104 ENSG00000065361 rs2271194 rs61939899
2  2.198148577.198835577 ENSG00000065413 rs4524134 rs2697288 rs6738721
6  6.84279922.84407274 ENSG00000065609 rs2016358 rs35791305
10  10.104585135.104956335 ENSG00000065613 rs72811696
```

I would like to remove the leading whitespace from the second column (there are two whitespaces separating columns 1 and 2 instead of one whitespace). Does anyone know a sed or awk command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cut:

```
cut -d " " -f 1,3- file
```

Output:

```
12 12.57428314.57490104 ENSG00000065361 rs2271194 rs61939899
2 2.198148577.198835577 ENSG00000065413 rs4524134 rs2697288 rs6738721
6 6.84279922.84407274 ENSG00000065609 rs2016358 rs35791305
10 10.104585135.104956335 ENSG00000065613 rs72811696
```

Answer (score 2):

`tr -s` (or `tr --squeeze-repeats`) will remove duplicate characters. So you if you want to replace *all* repeated spaces, you can write:

```
tr -s ' '   < input-file   > output-file
```

Input:

```
12  12.57428314.57490104 ENSG00000065361 rs2271194 rs61939899
2  2.198148577.198835577 ENSG00000065413 rs4524134 rs2697288 rs6738721
6  6.84279922.84407274 ENSG00000065609 rs2016358 rs35791305
10  10.104585135.104956335 ENSG00000065613 rs72811696
```

Output:

```
12.57428314.57490104 ENSG00000065361 rs2271194 rs61939899
2 2.198148577.198835577 ENSG00000065413 rs4524134 rs2697288 rs6738721
6 6.84279922.84407274 ENSG00000065609 rs2016358 rs35791305
10 10.104585135.104956335 ENSG00000065613 rs72811696
```

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed`, replacing more than one white-space characters with single space after the first column

```
sed -E 's/^(\S+)\s+/\1 /' ip.txt
```

For other versions, use

- `[[:space:]]` for `\s`
- `[^[:space:]]` for `\S`

or `:blank:` (space and tab characters) instead of `:space:` (white-space characters)

Answer (score 1):

This AWK replaces all occurrances of consecutive spaces with single space:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/ +/," ")' file 
12 12.57428314.57490104 ENSG00000065361 rs2271194 rs61939899
2 2.198148577.198835577 ENSG00000065413 rs4524134 rs2697288 rs6738721
6 6.84279922.84407274 ENSG00000065609 rs2016358 rs35791305
10 10.104585135.104956335 ENSG00000065613 rs72811696
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first space from each line:

```
$ sed 's/ //' file
12 12.57428314.57490104 ENSG00000065361 rs2271194 rs61939899
2 2.198148577.198835577 ENSG00000065413 rs4524134 rs2697288 rs6738721
6 6.84279922.84407274 ENSG00000065609 rs2016358 rs35791305
10 10.104585135.104956335 ENSG00000065613 rs72811696
```